# New developed Module contents not appearing on website. prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

sir, In my project i am adding new module. It was added in back office/ modules section. but, not appearing on website. code is as follows..

mymodule.php

---

```
<?php
if ( !defined( '_PS_VERSION_' ) )
exit;

class MyModule extends Module
{
public function __construct()
{
$this->name = 'mymodule';
$this->tab = 'mymodule';
$this->version = 1.6;
$this->author = 'Firstname Lastname';
$this->need_instance = 0;
parent::__construct();
$this->displayName = $this->l( 'My module' );
$this->description = $this->l( 'Description of my module' );
$this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.0', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
}

public function install()
{
  if (Shop::isFeatureActive())
    Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);

  return parent::install() &&
    $this->registerHook('leftColumn') &&
    $this->registerHook('header') &&
    Configuration::updateValue('MYMODULE_NAME', 'my friend');
}

public function hookDisplayLeftColumn($params)
{
  $this->context->smarty->assign(
      array(
          'my_module_name' => Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'),
          'my_module_link' => $this->context->link->getModuleLink('mymodule', 'display')
      )
  );
  return $this->display(__FILE__,'views/templates/hooks/mymodule.tpl');
}

public function hookDisplayRightColumn($params)
{
  return $this->hookDisplayLeftColumn($params);
}

public function hookDisplayHeader()
{
  $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/mymodule.css', 'all');
}   
}

?>
```

mymodule.tpl

---

location:views/templates/hooks/mymodule.tpl

```
<!-- Block mymodule -->
<div id="mymodule_block_left" class="block">
  <h4>Welcome!</h4>
  <div class="block_content">
    <p>Hello,
       {if isset($my_module_name) && $my_module_name}
           {$my_module_name}
       {else}
           World
       {/if}
       !       
    </p>   
    <ul>
      <li><a href="{$my_module_link}" title="Click this link">Click me!</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Block mymodule -->
```

mymodule.css

---

location:css/mymodule.css

```
div#mymodule_block_left p {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-style:italic;
}
```

display.php

---

location:controllers/front/display.php

```
<?php
class mymoduledisplayModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
  public function initContent()
  {
    parent::initContent();
    $this->setTemplate('display.tpl');
  }
}
```

display.tpl

---

location:controllers/front/display.php

```
<h1>well come !!!!!!!!</h1>
```

Comment: Is this Method is wrong.... Please guide me for this...

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested, your mistake seems to be on this line in the `public function install()`:

```
 $this->registerHook('leftColumn')
```

It should be:

```
$this->registerHook('displayLeftColumn')
```

The "*display*" keyword seems to be important.

One year later, Prestashop documentation still contains this crucial error.

**Note that**: `public function hookDisplayLeftColumn($params)`

don't appear in every pages (by example: it appear in product page, but not the home page).

There are some kind of specific hook for specific page. By example,

```
$this->registerHook('displayHome')

public function hookDisplayHome()
```

Added my module in the center of the home page (bellow already hooked modules). All the hooks can be found in the table `ps_hook`.

**Beware**: `public function hookDisplayRightColumn($params)`

doesn't work at all for me.

That page helped me a little bit with the same problem as yours: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Hooks

Well, I guess better worth an answer later than never...

**Edit**: I found how to activate columns:

In the back office, seek for the menu *preferences/themes* and click on the "*advanced settings*" button

[image]

Make sure that the columns you want are activated. In the list, click on *green check* or *red X* to reverse the visibility of columns in a specific module.

[image]